# Matrix Recurence Relation, $M_n=M_{n-1}M_{n-2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $M_0, M_1\in\mathbb R^{k\times k}$ be matrices, and define $M_n=M_{n-1}M_{n-2}$.
Then $M_n$ is a product of $F_n$ ($n$th Fibonacci number) many copies of $M_0$ or $M_1$.

How do I compute the limit $M_n^{1/F_n}$ as $n\to\infty$?

This is of course easy if $M_0$ and $M_1$ commute, but I'm not sure how to do it in a more general setting.

I'm particularly interested in the spectral norm $\|M_n\|^{1/F_n}$. Can we show, for example, that $\|M_n\|^{1/F_n} \ge \|\frac{M_0+M_1}{2}\|^{1/F_n}$?

Comment: Well, for instance, you could have $M_1M_0=0$ and then $M_n=0$ for all $n\geq 2$.  I doubt there is much you can say in general without some more specific information about $M_1$ and $M_0$.

Comment: Maybe I should suggest bounding in terms of $M_1^{0.618}M_0^{0.382}$ which is what we would get if $M_1$ and $M_0$ would commute.